# Fastest way to Loop through this Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
      Time          Entrysig     Exitsig
    7/16/2018 12:30 LongEntry   
    7/16/2018 13:00             LongExit
    7/16/2018 13:30     
    7/16/2018 14:00     
    7/16/2018 14:30     
    7/16/2018 15:00     
    7/16/2018 15:30 ShortEntry  LongExit <---wrong
    7/16/2018 17:00     
    7/16/2018 17:30     
    7/16/2018 18:00     
    7/16/2018 18:30     
    7/16/2018 19:00 LongEntry   ShortExit
    7/16/2018 19:30     
    7/16/2018 20:00     
    7/16/2018 20:30     
    7/16/2018 21:00 ShortEntry  LongExit
    7/16/2018 21:30     
    7/16/2018 22:00     
    7/16/2018 22:30     
    7/16/2018 23:00     
    7/16/2018 23:30     
    7/17/2018 0:00      
    7/17/2018 0:30      
    7/17/2018 1:00      
    7/17/2018 1:30      
    7/17/2018 2:00  LongEntry   ShortExit
    7/17/2018 2:30      
    7/17/2018 3:00
```

I have a data frame that looks like the above. I'm trying to make 2 other columns of just long and shorts without having to do a loop (if possible). It should say Long after a Long entry and continue to be long until a Long Exit signal. Same for the Short column. There can be 0s if it's not Long or Short or left blank. Either way is fine.

Note:
I have an issue with my exit signals where it'll still return an exit signal even if i've already gotten out of the trade so it should ignore those. (Can't get out of the same long trade twice). I've arrowed the one that's a mistake. Im working on fixing that too but that's a separate issue.

Output:

```
Date             EntrySig   ExitSig     Long    Short
7/16/2018 12:30 LongEntry               Long    
7/16/2018 13:00            LongExit     Long    
7/16/2018 13:30             
7/16/2018 14:00             
7/16/2018 14:30             
7/16/2018 15:00             
7/16/2018 15:30 ShortEntry  LongExit            Short
7/16/2018 17:00                                 Short
7/16/2018 17:30                                 Short
7/16/2018 18:00                                 Short
7/16/2018 18:30                                 Short
7/16/2018 19:00 LongEntry   ShortExit   Long    Short
7/16/2018 19:30                         Long    
7/16/2018 20:00                         Long    
7/16/2018 20:30                         Long    
7/16/2018 21:00 ShortEntry  LongExit    Long    Short
7/16/2018 21:30                                 Short
7/16/2018 22:00                                 Short
7/16/2018 22:30                                 Short
7/16/2018 23:00                                 Short
7/16/2018 23:30                                 Short
7/17/2018 0:00                                  Short
7/17/2018 0:30                                  Short
7/17/2018 1:00                                  Short
7/17/2018 1:30                                  Short
7/17/2018 2:00  LongEntry   ShortExit   Long    Short
7/17/2018 2:30                          Long    
7/17/2018 3:00                          Long
```

My attempt using iteration:

```
ls = []
trades = bt_data.reset_index()
for i in trades.index:
    if trades.iloc[i, trades.columns.get_loc('EntrySignal')] == 'LongEntry':
        ls.append('Long')
    elif i==0:
        ls.append('Flat')
    elif np.logical_and(ls[i-1] == 'Long', 
         trades.iloc[i-1, trades.columns.get_loc('ExitSignal')] 
         !='LongExit'):
            ls.append('Long')
        else:
            ls.append('Flat')
```

sample data as dict:

```
{'Date_Time': {0: Timestamp('2018-07-16 03:30:00'), 1: Timestamp('2018-07-16 04:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2018-07-16 04:30:00'), 3: Timestamp('2018-07-16 05:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2018-07-16 05:30:00'), 5: Timestamp('2018-07-16 06:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2018-07-16 06:30:00'), 7: Timestamp('2018-07-16 07:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2018-07-16 07:30:00'), 9: Timestamp('2018-07-16 08:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2018-07-16 08:30:00'), 11: Timestamp('2018-07-16 09:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2018-07-16 09:30:00'), 13: Timestamp('2018-07-16 10:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2018-07-16 10:30:00'), 15: Timestamp('2018-07-16 11:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2018-07-16 11:30:00'), 17: Timestamp('2018-07-16 12:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2018-07-16 12:30:00'), 19: Timestamp('2018-07-16 13:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2018-07-16 13:30:00'), 21: Timestamp('2018-07-16 14:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2018-07-16 14:30:00'), 23: Timestamp('2018-07-16 15:00:00'), 24: Timestamp('2018-07-16 15:30:00'), 25: Timestamp('2018-07-16 17:00:00'), 26: Timestamp('2018-07-16 17:30:00'), 27: Timestamp('2018-07-16 18:00:00'), 28: Timestamp('2018-07-16 18:30:00'), 29: Timestamp('2018-07-16 19:00:00'), 30: Timestamp('2018-07-16 19:30:00'), 31: Timestamp('2018-07-16 20:00:00'), 32: Timestamp('2018-07-16 20:30:00'), 33: Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:00:00'), 34: Timestamp('2018-07-16 21:30:00'), 35: Timestamp('2018-07-16 22:00:00'), 36: Timestamp('2018-07-16 22:30:00'), 37: Timestamp('2018-07-16 23:00:00'), 38: Timestamp('2018-07-16 23:30:00'), 39: Timestamp('2018-07-17 00:00:00'), 40: Timestamp('2018-07-17 00:30:00'), 41: Timestamp('2018-07-17 01:00:00'), 42: Timestamp('2018-07-17 01:30:00'), 43: Timestamp('2018-07-17 02:00:00'), 44: Timestamp('2018-07-17 02:30:00'), 45: Timestamp('2018-07-17 03:00:00'), 46: Timestamp('2018-07-17 03:30:00'), 47: Timestamp('2018-07-17 04:00:00'), 48: Timestamp('2018-07-17 04:30:00'), 49: Timestamp('2018-07-17 05:00:00'), 50: Timestamp('2018-07-17 05:30:00'), 51: Timestamp('2018-07-17 06:00:00'), 52: Timestamp('2018-07-17 06:30:00'), 53: Timestamp('2018-07-17 07:00:00'), 54: Timestamp('2018-07-17 07:30:00'), 55: Timestamp('2018-07-17 08:00:00'), 56: Timestamp('2018-07-17 08:30:00'), 57: Timestamp('2018-07-17 09:00:00'), 58: Timestamp('2018-07-17 09:30:00'), 59: Timestamp('2018-07-17 10:00:00'), 60: Timestamp('2018-07-17 10:30:00'), 61: Timestamp('2018-07-17 11:00:00'), 62: Timestamp('2018-07-17 11:30:00'), 63: Timestamp('2018-07-17 12:00:00'), 64: Timestamp('2018-07-17 12:30:00'), 65: Timestamp('2018-07-17 13:00:00'), 66: Timestamp('2018-07-17 13:30:00'), 67: Timestamp('2018-07-17 14:00:00'), 68: Timestamp('2018-07-17 14:30:00'), 69: Timestamp('2018-07-17 15:00:00'), 70: Timestamp('2018-07-17 15:30:00'), 71: Timestamp('2018-07-17 17:00:00'), 72: Timestamp('2018-07-17 17:30:00'), 73: Timestamp('2018-07-17 18:00:00'), 74: Timestamp('2018-07-17 18:30:00'), 75: Timestamp('2018-07-17 19:00:00')}, 'EntrySignal': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: 'LongEntry', 20: '', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: 'ShortEntry', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: 'LongEntry', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: 'ShortEntry', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: 'LongEntry', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: 'ShortEntry', 49: '', 50: 'LongEntry', 51: '', 52: 'ShortEntry', 53: '', 54: '', 55: '', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: 'LongEntry', 62: '', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: 'ShortEntry', 69: '', 70: '', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: 'LongEntry', 75: ''}, 'ExitSignal': {0: '', 1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: '', 9: '', 10: '', 11: '', 12: '', 13: '', 14: '', 15: '', 16: '', 17: '', 18: '', 19: 'ShortExit', 20: 'LongExit', 21: '', 22: '', 23: '', 24: '', 25: 'LongExit', 26: '', 27: '', 28: '', 29: '', 30: 'ShortExit', 31: '', 32: '', 33: '', 34: 'LongExit', 35: '', 36: '', 37: '', 38: '', 39: '', 40: '', 41: '', 42: '', 43: '', 44: 'ShortExit', 45: '', 46: '', 47: '', 48: 'LongExit', 49: '', 50: 'ShortExit', 51: '', 52: 'LongExit', 53: '', 54: '', 55: 'ShortExit', 56: '', 57: '', 58: '', 59: '', 60: '', 61: 'ShortExit', 62: 'LongExit', 63: '', 64: '', 65: '', 66: '', 67: '', 68: 'LongExit', 69: '', 70: 'ShortExit', 71: '', 72: '', 73: '', 74: 'ShortExit', 75: ''}}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written so far?

Comment: so the entry signal and exit signal are part of much bigger code block that are functions being passed into funtions etc. I have no idea where to start on the current task. Do you want me to post all the functions/full code etc?

Comment: @ialarmedalien added some code

Comment: Can you add your sample input df here by running `df.to_dict()` and add the output of that here?

Comment: @DJK done. Hope it's not too crude the way I added it but i appended it to the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove the erroneous exits, then you can achieve this by summing the entries and taking away the exits cumulatively and mapping the values (1,0) to (Long/Short, not long/not short):

```
df['Long'] = (df['EntrySignal'] == 'LongEntry').cumsum()  - (df['ExitSignal'] == 'LongExit').cumsum()
df['Short'] = (df['EntrySignal'] == 'ShortEntry').cumsum() - (df['ExitSignal'] == 'ShortExit').cumsum()

df['Long'] = df['Long'].map({1: 'Long', 0: ''})
df['Short'] = df['Short'].map({1: 'Short', 0: ''})
```

**Note:** with the erroneous entries the value will go below 0, and you will require more sophisticated logic.